# how to return from google directions to my app (android)

Tags: android, android-geofence, google-directions-api

i am writing an android app that uses fusedLocation along with google maps api and google directions api.

i define a geoFence and upon entering the geoFence the app launches the google directions app.

my question is how do i return to my app when the user arrived to his destination in google directions app? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user location with its destination location if it's equal then use `finish()` to finish your `Google Direction` activity or you can use `startActivityForResult()`